# Why would a function return undefined if you're not returning anything? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I have a function like so

```
var tellMeTrueOrFalse = function(collection, callback){
    each(collection, function(item){ 
            console.log((callback(item))?true:false);
        } 
    );
};
```

(`each` is a function that behaves like underscore's `_.each`). But when I try to `console.log()` the following:

```
tellMeTrueOrFalse([1,2,3], function(x) {return x%2 == 0;})
```

I get

```
false
true
false
undefined
```

Why am I getting `undefined?` when I'm not trying to return anything? How can I get it to just print and not returned the `undefined`?

Comment: are you running it in browser console?

Comment: You got "undefined" just when you are running the code in the console

Comment: Just don't do `console.log` when calling `tellMeTrueOrFalse`. Simply call it. The callback function will do other `console.log`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why am I getting undefined? when I'm not trying to return anything?

you are getting `undefined` because a function will always return something. If there is no explicit return statement, then default value is returned. And default value of a function is `undefined` as per [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

> To return a value other than the default, a function must have a
>   return statement that specifies the value to return. A function
>   without a return statement will return a default value. In the case of
>   a constructor called with the new keyword, the default value is the
>   value of its this parameter. **For all other functions, the default
>   return value is undefined.**

Comment: The console is logging each result of your `console.log()` PLUS the value of your function `tellMeTrueOrFalse()` which is `undefined`.